# AWS - Downloading files inside multiple folders inside s3 buckets using python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

```
import boto3
import os

S3_Object = boto3.client('s3', region_name='us-west-1' aws_access_key_id='access_key', aws_secret_access_key='secret_access_key')

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = 'bucket_name'
#response = s3.Bucket(bucket).objects.all()
# If you want to search only specific path of bucket,
response = s3.Bucket(bucket).objects.filter(Prefix='folder_name')

path = '/tmp/logs'
if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.makedirs(path)

for item in response:
    filename = item.key.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
    if filename.endswith('.csv.gz'):
        s3.Object(bucket, item.key).download_file(path + filename)
        print("success")
```

I am getting following error
    `raise NoCredentialsError
botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials`

So I have updated the `.aws/config` and `.aws/credentials`

On `.aws/config`:

```
[profile 1]
region=us-west-1
```

On `.aws/credentials`:

```
aws_access_key_id='access_key'
aws_secret_access_key='secret_access_key'
```

With no luck. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Remove the credentials and region from your code and ensure that the paths of your configuration files are relative to your home directory. Also ensure you have no AWS related environment variables set.

Comment: In the end i have installed AWS CLI which made it super easy